# How does multiclassing affect Eldritch Invocations with level prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, character-levels, eldritch-invocations

Ok... I'm making a Paladin of Conquest from Xanathar's Guide to Everything.  At around 9th level I want to Multiclass three levels into a Hexblade Warlock (also from XGtE).  I was wondering does having prior levels before Warlock affect some of the Eldritch Invocations that might have Level Prerequisites (such as the Lifedrinker and Thirsting Blade Invocations)?  As in am I able to select them for having the total Character Levels or does it only count towards Warlock Class levels?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Only your Warlock class matters for the prerequisites.

> In your study of occult lore, you have unearthed eldritch invocations, fragments of forbidden knowledge that imbue you with an abiding magical ability. **A level prerequisite refers to your level in this class**.

Other things, like Cantrips and Proficiency Bonuses, are based on your overall character level, but not Invocations.

Comment: @András proficiency bonus is character-level-dependent as well

Comment: @PixelMaster you are right